# Mysql Join with distinct values

Tags: mysql

Table Name : x

id name 
id  is primary key

```
1   xxxx
2   yyyy
```

Table name : y 
sno primary key
id foreign key
class

```
1 1 first 
2 1  second
```

OUTPUT

```
id 
xxxx first second
```

I do not want name to repeat for each row

```
SELECT x.name, y.class from x,y  WHERE x.id = y.id
```

This query output as xxxx first and xxxx second

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add in `GROUP BY y.id` then to avoid duplicate.

Comment: :Tried it but it gives only one row,there are two rows with id.

Comment: If you want two rows from tablex, use LEFT JOIN to join the table and use group by.

Comment: `SELECT x.name, y.class from x LEFT JOIN y ON x.id = y.id GROUP BY y.id`

Comment: :I want only the name from first table and class from second table but name should not come twice,those column are just for example.

Comment: `SELECT x.name, group_concat(y.class separator ', ' )  from x INNER JOIN y ON x.id = y.id GROUP BY y.id ` if i understand your reqd correctly.

Comment: :What should i put in y.class separator

Comment: My example put comma ie will return string with `first, second`. You could put space if you want eg `group_concat(y.class separator '  ' )` will return `first  second`

Comment: :You've under stood my requirement properly. SELECT x.name, y.class,y.section FROM x,y WHERE x.id = y.id then using php can i output as xxxx fourth a,first b.  xxxx is name, a and b is section and  fourth and first is classes.Can i do this ?

Comment: Yes. you could use group_concat to retrieve the concatenated string and use explode in php to split it into array. You could manipulate it as you like.

Comment: :say in group_concat(column,column2) is there in output column1 column2,how can i explode this

Comment: for eg, `$a="black,white,red"; $s_a = explode(',', $a);` $s_a is an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.name, y.class 
FROM x
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id, class FROM y) y 
        ON x.id = y.id;
```

Comment: :How can you select y.class from x table,it won't exist.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
set @yclass:='';
select  a.name,max(class) as class
from
(select @xname:=name as name,@yclass:=concat(@yclass,' ',y.class)  as class
from x join y
on x.id=y.id)a
```